# Parsing a text file and looking for a certain string

Tags: python, parsing, text

I've got a text file with EPA well information and they are coded by state. I want to break out each state into its own text file. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
from __future__  import print_function
import os, sys
import numpy as np


print(os.getcwd())

lines = [] #lines from file
with open('UCMR3_All.txt') as well_list:
    for line in well_list:
        if line == "AL":
            #what goes here?

well_list_output = open(os.path.join('..','well_list_output.txt'),'w')

for line in lines:
    well_list_output.write(line)

well_list_output.close()
```

Basically, I want to take a line that contains "AL" and output it to its own file. I've attempted to use `lines.append(line)` but that doesn't seem to help. I'll certainly accept helpful nudges or guidance in lieu of the answer!

Comment: Surely this question is on the site 10 times over.

Comment: for line in file1: if 'AL' in line: file2.write(line) ??

Comment: You can open two files in one `with` statement to read from one and write to another

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('UCMR3_All.txt') as well_list:
    for line in well_list.read().split('\n':
        if "AL" in line:
            lines.append(line)
```

Later you can just write the `lines` var into a file.

Basically, well_list is a file object. It's not a string and certainly not a list. If you want to read the file contents into a string, just use the `read()` method.
After reading the file, you can split it to lines using `split('\n')`.
Now everything left is to iterate through that list and save the good lines to a list. This can be done even in 2 lines:

```
with open('UCRM3_All.txt', 'r') as fileObj:
    lines[:] = [line for line in fileObj.read().split('\n') if "AL" in line]
```

This is called List Comprehension. You can read more online.

Now for printing the lines list to files (different files) you can:

```
for i in xrange(len(lines)):
    with open("f" + str(i) = ".txt", "w") as fileObj:
        fileObj.write(lines[i])
```

Comment: Iterating like _for **line** in **well_list**_
may avoid reading whole file content. Instead it read file line-by-line.
This may be important in case of very large files.